# Como abrir do MVC3 uma aplicação externa em MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação em MVC3 e tenho que chamar uma outra aplicação hospedada no mesmo servidor, esta em MVC5.

Devo usar um ajax?
Devo fazer um `iframe`?

Assim: tem um menu que é do MVC3 e que tem que ficar aparecendo. Então pensei que poderia ser `Iframe` ou uma div com chamada ajax do conteúdo da outra aplicação, o que devo usar?

Comment: Acho que `iframe` pode ser uma solução, sobretudo se são duas aplicações diferentes, sem acessos a dados uma da outra.

Comment: Esse é o meu problema, Cigano eu tenho que passar para MVC5 quem esta logado teria que passar via get eu pensei que teria algo diferente de Iframe não estou pesquisando dois dias não achei nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta para isso não é nada simples. Ela se baseia em *Single Sign On* (SSO) entre dois sites diferentes, usando alguma biblioteca de SSO como a [SSOLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSOLib/).

[Aqui tem um (enorme) tutorial de como fazer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-appl). [Este outro link seria o projeto da proposta do primeiro link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic). Em ASP.NET MVC, haverá algumas pequenas adaptações para que a aplicação se adeque a usar um *Controller* ao invés de uma *Page*.

Comment: Show como Sempre fera Cigando, kara muito obrigado mesmo.